# React - Unable to render components using a promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

My goal is to load an array with objects using an axios request, see code below:

```
function getSections() {
     return axios
    .get('https://localhost:44369/api/librarysections')
    .then(res => res.data
        .map(data => {
            return ({
                id: data.id,
                name: data.name,
                path: '/library/section/' + data.name,
                component: LibraryPage
            })
        })    
    )
    .then(data => data);
}
```

That list will then be used to generate a dynamic routing system passed to my component:

```
const pageRoutes = [
{
    path: '/home',
    name: 'Home',
    component: HomePage,
    icon: DashboardOutlined
},
{
    collapse: true,
    path: '/library',
    name: 'Library',
    component: LibraryPage,
    icon: LibraryBooksOutlined,
    views: getSections()
},
{ redirect: true, path: '/', pathTo: '/home', name: 'Home' }
];
```

And finally mapping the list to render the components:

```
<List>
       {routes.map((prop, key) => {
             if (prop.redirect || prop.parameter) {
                 return null;
             }

              if (prop.collapse) {
                  var data = Promise.resolve(prop.views);

                  data.then(res => {
                  console.log(res);
                  return (
                      <ListItem button >
                           <ListItemIcon >
                                 <prop.icon />
                           </ListItemIcon>
                           <ListItemText primary={prop.name}/>
                      </ListItem>
                    )
             )
          }
      })}         
</List>
```

But for some reason when I return the components, they do not show nor do I get an error and if I place a console log inside the return it will log to the console, meaning that is is going in.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a promise inside the **render** method like that.

You could perhaps use a function to return your page routes once you have the sections data:

```
const getPageRoutes = () => {
  return getSections()
    .then(sections =>
      [
        {
          path: '/home',
          name: 'Home',
          component: HomePage,
          icon: DashboardOutlined
        },
        {
          collapse: true,
          path: '/library',
          name: 'Library',
          component: LibraryPage,
          icon: LibraryBooksOutlined,
          views: sections
        },
        {
          redirect: true,
          path: '/',
          pathTo: '/home',
          name: 'Home'
        }
      ]
    )
}
```

And then, in your component, fetch the routes data on **componentDidMount** and only render the routes when you have the data:

```
class MyComp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super()

    this.state = {
      routes: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    getPageRoutes()
      .then(routes => this.setState({ routes }))
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <List>
        {this.state.routes.length &&
          this.state.routes.map((prop, key) => {
            if (prop.redirect || prop.parameter) {
              return null;
            }

            if (prop.collapse) {
              const data = prop.views;

              return (
                <ListItem button>
                  <ListItemIcon>
                    <prop.icon />
                  </ListItemIcon>
                  <ListItemText primary={prop.name}/>
                </ListItem>
              )
            }
          })
        }         
      </List>
    )
  }
}
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: You got it. That's exactly what was happening. Thank you so much! Life saver :)

Comment: No problem. Glad it helped.